# Is it possible to loop ws.send?

Tags: javascript, express, websocket

I wonder if it's possible loop ws.send and make it send a response each 8 seconds.

```
ws.send('000f{"func":"ping"}');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(()=> ws.send('000f{"func":"ping"}'), 8000)
```

If you are using ES5:

```
setInterval(function (){ ws.send('000f{"func":"ping"}') }, 8000))
```

Comment: it gives unexpected token error when i do

`...
});
setInterval(()=> ws.send('000f{"func":"ping"}', 8000)
});`

Comment: There was a missing paren at the end of ws.send. What IDE are you using? VS Code would tell you that. I've fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Nearly there - you got the missing paren, but took out the function declaration `() =>`